# gst-inspect-1.0 only works on full library path

Tags: gstreamer, yocto, openvino

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Bvt.png)

As shown in the screenshot, when I run gst-inspect-1.0 without full path, it got blacklisted.
However, if I use the full path to the library, everything works fine.

Of course when I ran 'gst-inspect-1.0 --plugin', it does not appear.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What is the result of `gst-inspect-1.0 audioanalytics`?  Did you try to debug the plugin detection using `GST_DEBUG=2 gst-inspect-1.0 <yourplugin>` ?

Comment: Try deleting the registry cache file at `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.x86_64.bin`. If you developed it on that machine and tried loading it while it failed it will be put on the blacklist. Re-scan after cache deletion will give it another chance.